# Changing the platform of rails application(platform specific gems)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-2

I have rails application built in windows machine changing app to linux machine.I found some gem windows specific.All I need to know is whether same are required for linux as well?

```
ruby-1.8.6 rails-2.3.8 Database sqlserver(windows)
ruby-1.8.6 rails-2.3.8 Database Mysql(ubuntu)
```

Here are those gems.

```
win32-clipboard (0.4.1)
win32-dir (0.3.1)
win32-eventlog (0.4.3)
win32-file (0.5.3)
win32-file-stat (1.2.3)
win32-process (0.5.1)
win32-sapi (0.1.3)
win32-service (0.5.2)
win32-sound (0.4.0)
windows-pr (0.6.2)
```

I need your suggestion.

Thanks

Comment: yeeah, you probably won't have a good time trying to port this app. Take `win32-eventlog`, for example. I'm pretty sure that it's *very* windows-specific. On the other hand, there are gems that are linux-only and won't work on windows. Why exactly do you want to change the platform?

Comment: Yes I am trying really hard to migrate this application.Could you tell me why these gems were used and should I install it or leave it?

Comment: "Could you tell me why these gems were used?" - how would *I* know? It's your app, you have the code :)

Comment: Hey Sergio Thanks I will look into it and soon will disturb you again :)